# Universal link to domain without path

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links

How to create app-site-association file for domain url (not domain url+ path) to deep link to ios application? Don't want to deep link if there is any path present in domain url.

Lets say my domain is www.test.com

so www.test.com -> deeplink to master app

I don't want www.test.com/locator.html to deeplink.

Is it fine to leave applinks paths blank?

```
{"applinks":{"apps":[],"details":[
 {
   "appID":"TeamID.bundle",
   "paths”:[]
 }
 ]} }
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace `apple-app-site-association` file with this

```
{
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [
            {
                "appID": "TeamID.bundle",
                "paths": ["/"]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

#### What is going on under the hood?

There are 3 ways to define paths:

`Static`: The entire supported path is hardcoded to identify a specific link, e.g. /static/terms

`Wildcards`: A * can be used to match dynamic paths, e.g. /books/* can matches the path to any author’s page. ? inside specific path components, e.g. books/1? can be used to match any books whose ID starts with 1.

`Exclusions`: Prepending a path with NOT excludes that path from being matched.

So, if you just define `"path": ["/"]` this means you just allow www.example.com/ nothing else.

#### References

[How to support Universal Links in iOS App and setup server for it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35609667/how-to-support-universal-links-in-ios-app-and-setup-server-for-it)

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution.
Set path as paths:["/"]